# How to implement Facebooks "Recent Logins" functionality

Tags: angular, symfony

I am developing a web app with Symfony and Angular (SPA App)
I am tasked to do the following like FB's recent logins:

[image]

The problem is that I don't have any idea where to start. Is this a remember me functionality? Coz I do not need my users to be logged in for N number of days. All I need is a way so that when the user clicked the picture the login form will be populated with credentials he used on previous session

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To start with information can be stored in localstorage and can be replayed from there for user to be logged again without entering credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage or cookie to save the information.

Be carefull, do not save the flat user credentials, but more like a encrypted data.

Once the user log in your app, you could send back to the front the data to save in localstorage/cookie.
Each user should have a specific key you could use to encrypt its username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Populating the credentials (which also implies saving them to the browser) could be a security risk. Don't do that.
If what you want is the user to login with just one click, you might as well just extend the expiration of your cookie to allow him to stay logged in for longer periods.

My approach would be to treat this like a soft login (as "remember me" would). Clicking the icon would request the user for the password to fully authenticate him once more

It all comes down to defining what fully authenticated and just authenticated means. I believe symfony already supports that distinction. Just make sure the rest of your project supports this, because they would have to check against fully authenticated, not just authenticated